# Text with gradient and custom font

Tags: javascript, css, xhtml, fonts, embedded-fonts

Ok here is my challenge, I have some `<h1>` tags that I want to convert into a custom font and apply a gradient from left to right.

Initially I was going for the idea of using cufon as this does both, but it turns out cufon only supports top to bottom gradients.

My only other option as far as I am aware is sIFR which I believe may support this, but its not preferable.

Does anyone have any recommendations? I have looked at typeface js which doesn't do gradients (I think) and CSS3 like moz-linear-gradient but this doesn't support applying it as a color.

Thanks!

Comment: "apply a gradient from left to right." Background or text color?

Comment: You're probably best off looking for some Javascript solutions.

Comment: Jiang : text color apparently.
@fire : I didn't find any other library providing this gradient option...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just manually hack [the cufón code](http://github.com/sorccu/cufon/blob/master/js/cufon.js) to change gradient direction for now?

I haven't tried or tested this myself, but I suspect the lines you'd want to change would be something like:

```
@973, for VML implementation
... fill.angle = 270;

@1364, for canvas implementation
... fill = g.createLinearGradient(viewBox.minX, 0, viewBox.maxX, 0);
```

Comment: That actually works but it's not spread evenly across the whole word - http://jsfiddle.net/DegtZ/

Comment: hmm, ok, how about: `createLinearGradient(0, 0, stretchedWidth, 0)`

Comment: thanks almost perfect, except it needs to apply the gradient across the whole sentence rather than each word.. http://jsfiddle.net/DegtZ/1/

Comment: I guess you would have to stop it treating each word as a separate object (`text.split(separators[separate])`?)... but then you would lose the ability to word-wrap. I guess this is why there is no horizontal gradient support by default: if you wanted to make it work completely you would have to trap window resizing and recreate the text each time in response to new word wrapping.

Answer (score 0):

See this: [Javascript example: text color to gradient](http://js-x.com/page/javascripts__example.html?run=630). Might help you out.

Answer (score 0):

I've developed a function that replace texts with canvas and it allow you to add gradient colors via CSS color property. Take a look at it and let me know if you like it.

https://github.com/msnazi/Gradient-for-text